# How I Implement Google picker in Angular CLI?

Tags: google-picker, angular-cli-v9

I want to implement Google Picker in my Angular Cli Project But Facing Issues is there any one who know How to Implement This??

Hey! I want to implement Google Picker in my Angular Cli Project But Facing Issues is This I want Google Picker Api Implement in my Angular cli Project